# How to make an Audit Trail / Activity Log using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a template already out there for PHP/MySQL that tracks the activity of a user? I already have audit trail but it only gets the time of logged in/log out. Not the changes or activity he did on his/her login.

Answer (score 3):

The best logging framework for php is [**log4php**](http://logging.apache.org/log4php/), since its from Apache itself. log4php has flexibility to choose the log storage (mysaql, text file  or email)

However the basic idea of user activity tracking is this:

1. Define the 'actions' performed by your website users, in a database table (action)
2. Map actions performed by the users using one relational table (user_action)

Comment: Thank you! I'm currently downloading the source code. I hope I understand how to insert it in my system. If this doesn't work, then I'll just insert a simple activity where it shows the name of the form that was edited by the user.

do you have an idea on how to install it?